# Python file generates points to plot on real time graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to have a python file execute another python file to come up with random y values to plot onto a graph? If so, how does one go about this?

Currently I have a file that generates a list of random y values:

```
import random
import threading


def main():
    for count in range(12000):
        y = random.randint(0,10000)
        print(y)

def getvalues():
    return [random.randint(0, 1000) for count in range(12000)]

def coordinate():
    threading.Timer(0.0001, coordinate).start ()
coordinate()

main()
```

and a file that generates a chart using random values (formula embedded):

```
import time
import random
from collections import deque
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import Random_Generation_List

start = time.time()

class RealtimePlot:
    def __init__(self, axes, max_entries = 100):
        self.axis_x = deque(maxlen=max_entries)
        self.axis_y = deque(maxlen=max_entries)
        self.axes = axes
        self.max_entries = max_entries

        self.lineplot, = axes.plot([], [], "g-")
        self.axes.set_autoscaley_on(True)

    def add(self, x, y):
        self.axis_x.append(x)
        self.axis_y.append(y)
        values = Random_Generation_List.getvalues()
        self.lineplot.set_data(self.axis_x, self.axis_y)
        self.axes.set_xlim(self.axis_x[0], self.axis_x[-1] + 1e-15)
        self.axes.relim(); self.axes.autoscale_view() # rescale the y-axis
        print(values)

    def animate(self, figure, callback, interval = 50):
        def wrapper(frame_index):
            self.add(*callback(frame_index))
            self.axes.relim(); self.axes.autoscale_view() # rescale the y-axis
            return self.lineplot

def main():

    style.use('dark_background')

    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    display = RealtimePlot(axes)
    axes.set_title("Real-time Plot")
    axes.set_xlabel("Time")
    axes.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
    while True:
        display.add(time.time() - start, random.random() * 100)
        plt.pause(0.001)

    display.animate(fig, lambda frame_index: (time.time() - start, random.random() * 100))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

How to I combine these and execute the file to generate random numbers to use as y (x is time) and plot them in real time on this graph?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you alter the code of the first file, or are you stuck with trying to capture the output from its `print(y)` statement?  Does it have to be a separate file, or can you just add code to the plot program?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do something similar to this:

```
import random_Y_file
values = random_Y_file.getValues()
print(values)
```

**In random_Y_files:**

```
def getValues():
    return [randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(100)] # Returns 100 numbers from 0 to 1000
```

Be sure that your python file you are working with is in the same folder as *random_Y_file.py*

Comment: I did this, however, it is still not working. I have the coordinates being printed, however they are not plotting on a graph, and the graph is blank. I have revised the code above to show what I updated.

Comment: Sorry for not answering. 
Are you sure it's not a problem in the graph then?

Comment: No more issues! Thanks :)